# Submit a csv to Google Adwords with the PHP API

Tags: php, api, google-ads-api

I want to create campain with the Adwords Api but i have already a csv of the campain, can i submit the csv'file to google like i do with Adwords editor ?

I have not find a function like submitafile to Adwords, if you can help me...

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

The adwords api operates at a lower level than that. Using the api you can *build* a program that creates a campaign from a CSV, but there isn't a simple "here is a CSV create a campaign" function.

Google provides some [sample code](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/tree/master/examples/AdWords) that shows how to perform common tasks using the api.